# How to disable JTable editing?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` and I want to disable editing it and it still can be able to highlight it I have this code:

```
private void tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
 boolean a = table.isEditing();
 if(a==false){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Editing Disabled");
 }
}
```

But when I remove `JOptionPane` it is still editable.

Comment: Documentation of `isEditing()`: "Returns true if a cell **is being** edited." - does **not** indicate if editing is disabled or not. The `TableModel` has a method `isCellEditable()` that controls if the table/cell is editable or not

Comment: What is the correct code? I wanted to disable editing the cell but still the row can be highlighted

Comment: the correct code is one where the model has that method returning `false` - model must be implemented/extended - see official  tutorial [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) - also recommended to include a [mcve] in the question

Answer (score 2):

If by highlighting you mean highlighting table rows, then you can override the method `isCellEditable` from the `DefaultTableModel` like this:

```
JTable table = new JTable() {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Using this approach, you can even disable specific cells by checking against the `row` and `column` parameters of the method.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have edited my answer accordingly